# Web addin fails in Outlook for Windows with: "Office.js has not fully loaded"

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

We created an Outlook web addin and it is working fine in OWA and in Outlook for Mac. On Outlook for Windows however, the addin only shows a blank page.

When attaching a debugger, we get the JavaScript error

> Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()
>   as part of it's loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize"
>   function").

[image: Debug error]

This is Outlook 2016.

We do call `Office.onReady` and we also tried inserting an empty body for `Office.initialize`.

I have a feeling that IE is not happy about the JavaScript we are using (Knockout.js perhaps?).  We also tried adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` but all to no avail.

How can I figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: Outlook desktop uses Internet Explorer to show add-ins, and some newer javascript features are not available. Can you test your add-in in OWA using Internet Explorer, and see if you're running into the same issue there? It may be that your add-in is utilizing one of these new features, and that is causing initialization to fail.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT: That's a good idea.  Surprisingly, it actually worked in IE but it did show me a tiny JavaScript error that I fixed and now the addin is working in Outlook as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Outlook Add-ins Team for this important comment. I was facing the similar issue, so I tried to run the add-in on IE11, and found the issue there, and by resolving that, it worked on Outlook desktop client too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the similar issue, so I tried to run the add-in on IE11 (to get the actual reason behind the issue), and found the issue there, and by resolving that, it worked on Outlook desktop client too.

Thanks @Outlook Add-ins Team for the important comment.